# Trying to center text and a button over an image

Tags: html, css

I need to know how to style the text and button over the image so that, even when the page width is resized, the text and button always stay in the center of the image.

```html
<div class="model-section">
  <img id="model" src="https://nextluxury.com/wp-content/uploads/Mens-Formal-Wear/Tuxedo/Tuxedo%20Mens%20Formal%20Wear%202.jpg" alt="Image cannot be displayed">
  <p class="model-p">Deals Of The Week</p>
  <button class="deals">Shop Now</button>
</div>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Put the text and Button in div and then style the `.model-section` and `div` section u just created.

```css
.model-section {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.info {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="model-section">
  <img id="model" src="https://nextluxury.com/wp-content/uploads/Mens-Formal-Wear/Tuxedo/Tuxedo%20Mens%20Formal%20Wear%202.jpg" alt="Image cannot be displayed" />
  <div class="info">
    <p class="model-p">Deals Of The Week</p>
    <button class="deals">Shop Now</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: no need to wrap the paragraph and the button